# How to prove $\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ is a real number when $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I replaced $z$ with $x+yi$ and I assumed you have to get rid of the $i$'s to prove it's a real number. Would really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: It isn't in general; you have neglected a hypothesis on $z$.

Comment: Now that you have added $|z|=1$, we are relieved...

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not true, take $z = 2i$ and $n=1$.

Comment: In fact, for any $n$, his function is meromorphic, and so its image is open in the complex plane.  Hence not the real line.

Answer (score 2):

The property does not hold in general. It is trivially true if $z^n$ is real. It also holds when $|z|=1$. In that case, note that if $|w|=1$ then $1/w=\overline{w}$ and
$$\frac{w}{1+w^2}=\frac{1}{\overline{w}+w}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Very thorough answer.

Comment: In general for $|z| \neq 1$ it holds $\iff z^n=\overline{z}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in general is to demonstrate that the expression is equal to its conjugate, let’s try if in that case it works.

$\big[$ EG think to: $\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\big]$

In this case you can find quite easily some couterexamples. In the case you'll need it, here is a complete solution for the problem **by conjugation** considering also the case $|z|\neq 1$:

[image]

Thus **in general** for $|z| \neq 1$ the equality holds $\iff z^n=\overline{z}^n$.

EG

$\begin{cases}
Im(z)=0 \quad \forall n \\
n=3 \implies Im(z)=\pm \sqrt{3} Re(z) \\
etc.
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

Since,  $|z|= 1$ then $\bar{z} =\frac1z$ hence, $$\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}} = \frac{1}{\color{red}{\overline{z^n}+z^{n}}} =\frac{2}{Re(z^{n})}\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: Coul you explain what is meant by Re?

Comment: @FintanColaco do you know about the real part of a complex number?

Comment: Yeah just wondering how you got to the final answer